# Active Adblock Plus shows weird error in Chrome JS Console

Tags: google-chrome, console, malware, adblock

Every page I browse with Chrome shows this error in the console:

extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8

> Error in event handler for (unknown): SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Failed to parse the rule '::content #GoogleLeaderBoardAdUnit, ::content .insert_advertisement, ::content .ads-fif, ::content a[href^="http://www.gamebookers.com/cgi-bin/intro.cgi?], ::content .ads324-wrapper, ::content #rhsadvert, ::content .ad-lead, ::content #gtv_tabSponsor, ::content #adsense1, ::content #ap_adframe, ::content #adv_google_300, ::content #iqd_rightAd, ::content #bottom-side-ad, ::content #right_side_bar_ami_ad, ::content .ipm-sidebar-ad-middle, ::content .topad-area, ::content #advertising_728, ::content .logo_AdChoices, ::content #right-uppder-adverts-container, ::content .article_ad { display: none !important; }'.
>       at chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/include.preload.js:345:25handler @ extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8exports.handle @ extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:100EventImpl.dispatch_ @ extensions::event_bindings:384EventImpl.dispatch @ extensions::event_bindings:401propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19$Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:94dispatchOnMessage @ extensions::messaging:316

If I deactivate Adblock Plus (1.9.3) the error message is gone. If I activate Adblock Plus the error shows up again, even if every other extension is deactivated. I am worried Adblock is not the problem, but makes the problem visible.

Also a project I just finished got declined by Google Adwords with the reason "Malware". Im waiting for a callback from Adwords tech support for more details.

I am worried that my system or browser is infected with some sort of malware which already found its way into my web projects. I have no idea what to do about it.

I am running the latest Chrome on Yosemite 10.10.5

Any suggestions?

Comment: It *appears* somethings trying to insert adds into pages you visit. Adblock would attempt to block these so its not illogical that its highlighting something. Check chrome://plugins for anything you dont think should be there. Also this should be migrated to SU, its not programming specific.

Comment: thanks, plugins seem normal... SU = Super User Forum?

Comment: Yeah, its more a software/systems issue than a programming one which is what Stack Overflow is for

Answer (score 22):

I uninstalled and reinstalled Adblock in Chrome and the error message has ceased.

Comment: Chrome extensions are [sketchy](http://lifehacker.com/many-browser-extensions-have-become-adware-or-malware-1505117457)...

Comment: Thaks alot. It works for me :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're working on local development, until this is resolved, you can either pause Adblock or set it to "Don't run on this page".

Comment: I encountered this error today, Chrome `67.0.3396.87 ` and tried whitelisting the page and adblock does turn grey on my page but still the above error shows up in console. :(

Comment: 2022 and this still happens. Only goes away if you disable Adblock completely from the Manage extensions page

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by an invalid CSS selector in one of the EasyList filters that are being used in Adblock Plus. It was fixed by one of the EasyList authors [only a few hours after this question was created on October 14](https://hg.adblockplus.org/easylist/rev/570ed2c43427).

Comment: aaaaaaand it's back

Comment: seeing this too now; any suggestions? updated my easylist filters already.

Comment: If it's indeed the same problem, I'd recommend reporting it to EasyList in case they're not aware of this issue yet. The easiest way to do so is by posting [on their forum](https://forums.lanik.us/) or by creating an issue [in their respective GitHub repository](https://github.com/easylist).

Comment: I'm not on Adblock Plus (just the free version) and I'm getting this same console log error (it threw me off 'cause it started showing on my local/internal dev server where I'm currently developing a site, but which has no ads).

Comment: Yep, I am having it too.

Comment: Yup, seeing it again now >:(