# React not Rendering Imported Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just starting out trying to build a react webpage and having issues getting my first component to render successfully. I've tried many json solutions and am wondering if it's just a syntax error in my code at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);


reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import './App.scss';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Layout from './components/Layout'


function App() {
  return (
    <>
     <BrowserRouter>
     <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />} />
     </Routes>
     </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  )
}



export default App;
```

components/Layout/index.js

```
import './index.scss';
//import Sidebar from '../Sidebar';

const Layout = () => {
    return (
        <>
        Hello
        </>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Errors I'm receiving in the browser

````
Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined
    at onScriptLoad (adblock-onpage-icon-cs.js:172:3)
    at adblock-onpage-icon-cs.js:183:2
onScriptLoad @ adblock-onpage-icon-cs.js:172
(anonymous) @ adblock-onpage-icon-cs.js:183
react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
    at useRef (react.development.js:1630:1)
    at BrowserRouter (index.tsx:151:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)```
````

Comment: I can't see where you imported React in your index.js file and it's being used

Comment: Can you also add your `index.html` file and how did you init this app? Did you use `create-react-app`?

Comment: apologies, the import react statement was there, was an issue with the codeblock.

Comment: was created using create-react-app

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: try adding console.log(Layout) to the App.js component and check the console to see what gets logged

Comment: It is not working. I added the console.log and i'm getting quite a few invalid hook call errors.

Comment: Can you add them here?

Comment: Remove BrowserRouter for index.js    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter> to <App />

Comment: Nothing changed when doing that.

Comment: remove all  scss imports

Comment: These are adblock errors in your logs,  see  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136226/active-adblock-plus-shows-weird-error-in-chrome-js-console

Comment: commented out all scss imports and removed adblock and nothing changed.

Comment: Open the app in another browser and restart chrome

Comment: Tried in edge, same result. I downloaded the react dev tools for the browser and looked at the component field and it's finding none.

Comment: And the edge has the same error with adblock?

Comment: It has quite a bit less errors, but still showing the same errors found in the original post.

Comment: Show all errors

Comment: All errors can be found in the original post. the hook call error is shown in the output about 4 times

Comment: Show your package.json

Comment: react-router-dom not installed

Comment: You only need one top level BroswerRouter

Comment: npm i -s react-router-dom

Comment: Removed all the browserrouter calls besides in index.js. used npm i -s react-router-dom inside my project folder and still the same errors.

Comment: Show  node -v in your terminal

Comment: remove  node_modules and npm i . Restart npm start

Comment: If your node version is above stable 16.15 then downgrade it to 16.15

Comment: thanks for all your help. This led me to figure out that for some reason I had installed dependencies and whatnot in the wrong place when I first set this up. Just created a new project and did this same thing and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove Be happy and happy hacking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to having installed dependencies accidently outside of the project folder. Set up a brand new project and installed everything successfully and was able to get it working successfully.

[image: Layout Component]

Answer (score 0):

you just remove `<BrowserRouter>` from index.js or App.js